# Carriage return in CSV cell using XSL

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am having trouble with some XSL reports. Basically, I am spitting everything out to CSV, and this part is working fine, however sometimes I need to get two values into the same cell but on different lines.

I have tried putting each string in `<p>` tags, placing a `<br />` between the lines, placing `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` and `<xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>` between the two items, however they always end up in different cells.

The part of the XSL that is meant to put the two or more items in the one cell, with carriage returns between each item, is below.

```
<xsl:template name="getRoutingRules">
 <xsl:param name="itemID" />
 <xsl:for-each select="/aka-Architect/Schema/Relationships/OwnerTerm[@ID=$itemID]">
  <xsl:if test="@Entity='Subject'">
    <xsl:for-each select="./Routing_Rules/*">
      <xsl:if test="@Entity='Routing Rules'">
          <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@Name"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="''" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        <br />
        <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

```
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:param name="replace"/>
<xsl:param name="with"/>
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Full XSL is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--CSV-->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://www.stylusstudio.com/xquery">
<xsl:template match="/aka-Architect">
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="Schema/Hierarchy/TopTerm"/>
    <!--xsl:apply-templates/-->
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="GetTopTerm" match="Schema/Hierarchy/TopTerm">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>BCS Path</xsl:text>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>Descriptor</xsl:text>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>Descriptor Type</xsl:text>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>Description</xsl:text>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:text>Routing Rules</xsl:text>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--<xsl:call-template name="GetFunctions" />
  <xsl:call-template name="GetActivities" />-->
  <xsl:call-template name="GetSubjects" />
</table>
</xsl:template>



<!---Get Function -->
<xsl:template name="GetFunctions">
<xsl:for-each select="/aka-Architect/Entities/Function/Items">
  <xsl:for-each select="./*">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//ixPath" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//BCSLevel"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//Description"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


<!---Get Activity -->
<xsl:template name="GetActivities">
<xsl:for-each select="/aka-Architect/Entities/Activity/Items">
  <xsl:for-each select="./*">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//ixPath" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//BCSLevel"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//Description"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<!---Get Subject -->
<xsl:template name="GetSubjects">
<xsl:for-each select="/aka-Architect/Entities/Subject/Items">
  <xsl:for-each select="./*">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//ixPath" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//Name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//BCSLevel"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select=".//Description"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:call-template name="getRoutingRules">
          <xsl:with-param name="itemID" select='@ID' />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>



<!-- FIND ROUTING RULES -->
<xsl:template name="getRoutingRules">
<xsl:param name="itemID" />
<xsl:for-each select="/aka-Architect/Schema/Relationships/OwnerTerm[@ID=$itemID]">
  <xsl:if test="@Entity='Subject'">
    <xsl:for-each select="./Routing_Rules/*">
      <xsl:if test="@Entity='Routing Rules'">
        <p>
          <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@Name"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'&quot;'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="with" select="''" />
          </xsl:call-template>
        </p>
        <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


<!-- replace " with ' -->
<xsl:template name="replace-string">
 <xsl:param name="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="replace"/>
 <xsl:param name="with"/>
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="text"
          select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!-- (c) 2016. CorpMem Business Solutions. All rights reserved.-->
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Cheers,
John

EDIT: Added Full XSL at request.

Comment: Your question speaks of CSV - yet your code generates an HTML table. Those are two *very* different things.If you want to produce a "carriage return" in HTML, you need to output `<br/>`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k They are very different, yes, and I am not sure how all this works but if I don't use the HTML table tags everything is crammed into 1 cell. I have tried `<br />` however this puts everything into a new cell below.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you describe. You should use HTML table tags if you want the result to be an HTML page displayed in a browser. If you want a .csv text file, why don't you produce it directly? Seems like there's something else in your processing chain that you have left out.

Comment: @michael.hor257k We use a specific type of software that takes my XSL and XML files and then creates the output. I might have to go and talk to the software developers to see how I can get the correct output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF

> ```
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
> ```

> ```
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
> ```

So you just have to make sure your cells are delimited by quotes, and you can put line breaks in them.

Comment: If I add quotation marks, they just get printed on the screen. The only way that I am able to put the data in cells in a CSV is to use HTML Table Elements in my XSL.

Comment: They do because it is the CSV library's job to add them when it creates the CSV. You should add your code.

Comment: Added the XSL. Hopefully it helps. When I added the quotes in it showed on the screen.